# Version problem with fresh Maven after changing java version

Tags: maven

I set up maven on a fresh developer environment, added to the path and checked version. I realized I had java 17 in my java_home so I switched it to the java 11 installation due to having some old projects needing work.

After I did that I got en error when running mvn -v since it claims MavenCli has been compiled for Java 17. But what exactly has been compiled and where? Because no matter what I do I can't get it to work with my java 11 now.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

This is just in Windows in the command prompt/bash since I haven't even setup my IDE and don't have any projects.

I have tried removing Maven completely, restarting and redoing it, but no matter what I do Maven seems locked to Java 17.

Comment: What is the full output of `mvn --version`?

Comment: It was that the bloody 4.0.0 requires Java 17.  
I feel like an idiot. I chose 3.9.6 instead.  
  
What I wrote plus various classes.  
  
  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022)

etc.

Comment: Technically you can run your build with JDK17 and use `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>` would create JDK11 code... but Maven 4 is alpha-13 state not formally in GA...

Answer (score 0):

It was Maven 4.0.0 which requires Java 17